# How to have one Scaffold with one BottomNavigationBar and multiple MaterialApp.routes

Tags: flutter, material-design, bottomnavigationview, navigator, scaffold

By looking at the Material Design document about [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#behavior) I can see multiple pages with nice transitions that use only one BottomNavigationBar, and probably one Scaffold.

I would like to replicate this but I struggle to do so, and previous answers lead to wrong solutions with bad animation and multiple Scaffold.

I want, one MaterialApp with multiple routes and one scaffold with one bottom bar. By tapping the bar items, I want to change the routes and so, the page and keep the actual bottom bar.

What is good the practice to implement this?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The answer is the one that @pskink provided;  you should use the **Navigator** widget with nested routes, meaning you must implement nested navigation.